# Clicking on answer item from the achivements dialog doesn't close the dialog

Tags: bug, answers, hyperlinks, achievements-dialog

Achivements dialog can contains items linked to the answers (e.g. when your answers got votes or you accept an answer for your question). In that case if you already had opened a page via that link, further click on the item doesn't close the dialog nor reload the answer page.

> [image: popup link to answer]

As far as I understand this happened due to using anchor link - a part with `#number` at the end.